# How do I modify a determined group of chars inside a string? I need to modify them in a numerical way

Tags: php, string, char

I need to decrease the ansi char value if the character is above 159, decrease it by 128. I've used the following function but doesn't do anything. Is there any way to access and modify the chars within a PHP string ala ANSI C char? how?

```
function ConvertChars($str)
{
    $result = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i)
    {
        if ((int)$str[$i] > 159) 
            $result.= $str[$i]-128;
        else
            $result.= $str[$i];     
    }

    return $result;     
}
```

Comment: I am curious why you are doing this in the first place.

Comment: Because I'm coding a PHP scripts that reads a serverinfo keys from an old game which uses chars above 159 as normal chars but in a different color. This obviously represents a problem when you try to display on a web site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the binary number value of the character you want [`ord()`](http://www.php.net/ord) and to do the inverse, to generate the character from its number value to a byte you want [`chr()`](http://www.php.net/chr).

```
function ConvertChars($str)
{
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; ++$i)
    {
        if (ord($str[$i]) > 159) {
            $str[$i] = chr(ord($str[$i]) - 128);
        }
    }

    return $str;     
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works, and it's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: If the answer addresses your question please be sure to accept it as this helps people with similar questions to more easily find the answer.

Comment: Done, thanks Sherif, I'm still a newbie on stackoverflow!